# sails.js + socket.io: Can't receive standard sail.js/socket.io messages on client

Tags: socket.io, sails.js

With the newest beta version from sails.js (0.10.0-rc5) I'm trying to do this:

```
sails new Test
cd Test 
sails generate  api user
```

Create file assets/js/test.js

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337');
socket.on('connect',function() {
    console.log('connected');
    socket.request('/user',{}, function(users) { 
        console.log(users); 
    });

    socket.on('message', function(msg) {
        console.log("Message: " + msg);
    });

    socket.on('user', function(msg) {
        console.log("User: " + msg);
    });
});
```

My problem

*console.log("User: " + msg);* and *console.log("Message: " + msg);* aren't receiving any messages when I create or update a user. 
According to the documentation and to the **Intro to sails.js** video this socket.io messages should be send automatically.

What am I missing to successfully receive sails.js/socket.io message on my client?

Comment: what did you do to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

If you installed the latest NPM version, then you'll also have the latest version of the [Sails socket client](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js/blob/8f6bee080ebe1547acfdb3f52714e37f4eebf753/README.md).  Check out its [page on Github](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js#basic-usage) for basic usage, then check out the [PubSub section of the Sails migration guide](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/Upgrading.md#pubsub), which explains the differences between Sails v0.9.9x (which the Intro to Sails.js video shows) and the latest version.  In the end, your code should look more like:

```
// Note--the latest sails socket client connects automatically!

// Get all of the existing users--also subscribes to socket events
// for those users
io.socket.get('/user', function serverResponded (body, sailsResponseObject) {
    console.log(body);
});

// When a socket message about a user is received, display it
io.socket.on('user', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

**Notes**

1. Pay special attention to the section in the migration guide about `.watch()`; it means that you don't get `create` events automatically anymore and have to subscribe to them in your server code using (for the `User` model) `User.watch()`.
2. Remember that in general you don't get socket messages about actions that you yourself trigger, so if you want to test that your message-handling code is working, it's best to open up two windows (or tabs) and do your requests in one while watching for events in the other.
3. Also remember that you only get subscribed to socket events when you make a *socket request*; an AJAX call to `/users` will retrieve all of the current users, but you won't be subscribed to events.  It has to be done using `io.socket.get`.